# STM32L4 SystemCoreClock access crashes the program during HAL initialization

Tags: stm32, linux, stm32cubemx

I'm trying to blink an LED on a Nucleo-L476 with CubeMX and ST's HAL. It worked perfectly on Windows (System Workbench). Now, I'm trying to do the same on Linux with CubeMX and [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) (my favorite IDE) and [OpenOCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_Cortex-M_development_tools#Debugging_tools). I am now able to compile and debug the target.

However, the program crashes during HAL initialization. More precisely, when it tries to access the `SystemCoreClock` variable. The following code is called from `HAL_Init();` in `main()`:

```
__weak HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_InitTick(uint32_t TickPriority)
{
  uint32_t tickNum=123, *ptr1=NULL, *ptr2=NULL; // Added by me to debug
  ptr1 = &tickNum;                              // Added by me to debug
  ptr2 = &SystemCoreClock;                      // Added by me to debug
  tickNum = SystemCoreClock;                    // Added by me to debug *** crash here ***

  /* Configure the SysTick to have interrupt in 1 ms time basis */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000);   // *** Crash here ***

  /* Configure the SysTick IRQ priority */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, TickPriority ,0);

  /* Return function status */
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

I could replace `SystemCoreClock` by a constant, but the variable needs to be modified further down the line anyway. `SystemCoreClock` is declared in *system_stm32l4xx.h* and defined in *system_stm32l4xx.c*. Both files are part of the project.

** extern variable `SystemCoreClock` seems to have two different addresses.

Normal stuff `(ptr1 == &ticknum` and `*ptr1 == ticknum)`:

```
(gdb) p &tickNum
$3 = (uint32_t *) 0x20017fdc
(gdb) p ptr1
$4 = (uint32_t *) 0x20017fdc
(gdb) p *ptr1
$5 = 123
```

Strange stuff (`ptr2 != &SystemCoreClock` and `*ptr2 != SystemCoreClock`):

```
(gdb) p &SystemCoreClock
$6 = (uint32_t *) 0x20000004 <SystemCoreClock>
(gdb) p ptr2
$7 = (uint32_t *) 0x681b4b20
(gdb) p *ptr2
$8 = 0
```

When I say 'crash', I mean the program falls in an infinite loop in startup_stm32l476xx.s:

```
/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an
 *         unexpected interrupt.  This simply enters an infinite loop, preserving
 *         the system state for examination by a debugger.
 *
 * @param  None
 * @retval : None
*/
    .section    .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
Default_Handler:
Infinite_Loop:
    b    Infinite_Loop
```

Trying to narrow down the search, I noticed that a variable declared outside a function is not properly accessed from within the function:

```
uint32_t dummyVar = 123;

void dummyFunc()
{
    uint32_t loc = 123;
    uint32_t *p = &loc;
    p = &dummyVar;            // Debugger says &dummyVar = 0x20000004 and p = 0x011a3b01
    __asm("nop");
    __asm("nop");
    __asm("nop");
    loc = dummyVar;           // *** Crash here
}
```

The variable `p` here points outside the RAM, which starts at 0x20000000. The nop instructions make sure `p = &dummyVar;` is really executed and the debugger doesn't fool me.

Any idea?

Comment: what is the crash about? you can find information about the crash by reading register SCB. See this link : [Programming manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/6c/3a/cb/e7/e4/ea/44/9b/DM00046982.pdf/files/DM00046982.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00046982.pdf). You can first look at SHCSR register to see what kind of error that was caught by cpu.

Comment: The memory at 0xE000ED24 reads 0x00000000. See section 'Edit 2' in the post about the 'crash'.

Comment: is this a duplicate of the stackoverflow question?

Comment: The memory at 0xE000ED24 reads 0x00000000. See section 'Edit 2' in the post about the 'crash'.

Comment: I noticed in the backtrace that the WWDG (system window watchdog) interrupt handler was triggered. There is an alias from WWGD IRQ handler to the default handler (infinite loop).

Comment: Make sure that your function handling the tick incrementation is working correctly.  The default function for this is called HAL_IncTick() and the variable that must be incremented is called uwTick. Check so that your stack pointer is correct (should probably be 0x2004FFFF). Also check so that your vector tables are being setup correctly.

Comment: If you are looking for help, you may want to ask your question about STM32 here:
https://st-microelectronics.jiveon.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QBS / Qt Creator was adding the -fPIC ([position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)) option to gcc command line in my back. Someone solved it [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64276/qbs-how-to-remove-fpic-option).